# ASP.NET get all values of radiobuttonlist that in repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, radiobuttonlist

aspx file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_sorular" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="div_soru">
     <div class="div_soru_wrapper">
         <%#Eval("Subject")%>
         <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList_secenekler" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("TypeId").ToString() == "1" %>'
            DataSource='<%#Eval("Secenekler")%>' DataTextField='<%#Eval("OptionName")%>' DataValueField='<%#Eval("OptionId")%>'>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
         <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList_secenekler" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("TypeId").ToString() == "2" %>'
            DataSource='<%#Eval("Secenekler")%>' DataTextField='<%#Eval("OptionName")%>' DataValueField='<%#Eval("OptionId")%>'>
         </asp:CheckBoxList>
     </div>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and codebehind:

```
SpAnketDataContext db = new SpAnketDataContext();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         BindRepeaterSorular();
    }
}

protected void ImageButton_kaydet_OnCommand(object source, CommandEventArgs e)
{

}

private void BindRepeaterSorular()
{
    int anket_id = 3;

    var sorular = from soru in db.TableSurveyQuestions
                  where soru.SurveyId == anket_id
                  select new
                  {
                      soru.TypeId,
                      soru.Subject,
                      soru.QuestionId,
                      soru.SurveyId,
                      soru.QueueNo,
                      SurveyTitle = soru.TableSurvey.Title,
                      TypeName = soru.TableSurveyQuestionType.TypeName,

                      Secenekler = from secenekler in soru.TableSurveyOptions
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       secenekler.OptionId,
                                       secenekler.OptionName,
                                       secenekler.QuestionId,
                                   }
                  };

    Repeater_sorular.DataSource = sorular;
    Repeater_sorular.DataBind();
}
```

this is the code that I try to get values but I can get only last radiobuttonlist values.

```
protected void Repeater_sorular_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater_sorular.Items)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1 = (CheckBoxList)e.Item.FindControl("CheckBoxList_secenekler");
            RadioButtonList RadioButtonList1 = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList_secenekler");
            if (CheckBoxList1 != null)
            {
                foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
                {
                    TableSurveyVote votes=new TableSurveyVote();
                    votes.MemberId=1;
                    votes.OptionId=Int32.Parse(li.Value);

                    db.TableSurveyVotes.InsertOnSubmit(votes);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }

            if (RadioButtonList1 != null)
            {
                foreach (ListItem li in RadioButtonList1.Items)
                {
                    TableSurveyVote votes=new TableSurveyVote();
                    votes.MemberId=1;
                    votes.OptionId=Int32.Parse(li.Value);

                    db.TableSurveyVotes.InsertOnSubmit(votes);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You asking us what is wrong ? :) what is your issue here ? and where ?

Comment: last code block I want to get all radio button list values, But I get the last one values.For Examle I have 4 radiobuttonlist. I get last one values 4 times.

Comment: you are right I cant explane :(

Comment: this is probably because you not found the control base on the populate from `foreach` loop (the `item`) but base on the `e.Item`

Comment: yes this is answer. thanks. I coulnt see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the same results as you say on the comment because you do not use the populate from the `foreach` loop (the `item`) but use the same reference `e.Item` on the loop.